# tapply(dat$`lagged Date`, INDEX = dat$Location, FUN = diff(dat$`lagged Date`))

Tags: r, tapply

Can someone explain me why this is not working?

```
tapply(dat$`lagged Date`, INDEX = dat$Location, FUN = diff(dat$`lagged Date`))
```

I receive the following error:

> Error in match.fun(FUN) :    'diff(dat$`lagged Date`)' is not a
>   function, character or symbol

```
structure(list(`lagged Date` = structure(c(1466306880, 1466307060, 
1466307240, 1466307420, 1466307600, 1466307780), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Location = c(309, 309, 309, 309, 309, 
309), Duration = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Latitude = c(53.50205667, 
53.501915, 53.50183667, 53.50178833, 53.50184, 53.50186167), 
    Longitude = c(-3.354733333, -3.354096667, -3.353838333, -3.353673333, 
    -3.353711667, -3.353741667), `Number of Records` = c(1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), Speed = c(0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Sum of Var` = c(38, 
    38, 38, 38, 38, 38), check = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("lagged Date", 
"Location", "Duration", "Latitude", "Longitude", "Number of Records", 
"Speed", "Sum of Var", "check"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but using only `diff` as the `FUN` part works and produces this output:

```
tapply(dat$`lagged Date`, INDEX = dat$Location, FUN = diff)

$`309`
Time differences in mins
[1] 3 3 3 3 3
```

If you want to convert the output into `hours`, you can do that by selecting only the values of the `difftime`-list object and convert those:

```
as.numeric(tapply(dat$`lagged Date`, INDEX = dat$Location, FUN = diff)[[1]], units = "hours")
```

Output then looks like this:

```
[1] 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05
```

Comment: Yes but the time difference is in secs not in hours. I want to have it in hours. Is it possible?

Comment: Hm, that depends on what your output should look like. See my edit.